# Did any vulcans ever appear in TNG other than Spock and Sarek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, vulcan

The question is pretty straightforward:

The only Vulcans I ever saw on TNG were Spock and Sarek. Did any other Vulcans make any appearances? I know there was an effort to avoid Vulcan stories, but surely Picard and co. must have run into some other Vulcan besides Spock and his dad.

Comment: The dupe offers multiple examples of Vulcans on the Enterprise-D

Comment: you didn't watch the entire series I take it? ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell it's been a while (~20 years) - any time I have now, I devote to DS9 and VOY - which I am very far from completing.

Comment: I think that this should be reopened; it asks for Vulcans in the whole series, even in other places/roles, not necessarily being part of the Crew of the Enterprise: i.e. [this character](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Savar) appeared on TNG but was not serving aboard the Ent-D, and would be offtopic on the dupe.

Comment: This was closed as a dupe, not sure why it's in the re-open queue, but nothing's changed since it was closed. I'm satisfied to leave closed at this point.

Comment: I'ts me that cast the vote to reopen this question, for the reasons explained in my previous comment. Being on the Ent-D and on TNG is not the same thing: the Ent-D was featured also on a movie and on crossover episodes with other series, while in TNG we see plenty of charatcers that don't belong to the ship's crew.